# Limit points, closure, isolated points

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A=${$(-1)^n + 2/n :n=1,2,3,.....$} and $B= ${$x\in Q : 0<x<1$}

Answer the following questions for each set:

a) What are the limit points?

b) is the set open? closed?

c) Does the set contain any isolated points?

d) Find the closure of the set.

My attempt:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. I have one little comment. Since you have already ascertained that $-1$ does not belong to $A$, the phrase "except -1" in (c) is not needed.